# How does $3^{n+1}-3+2\cdot 3^{n+1}$ become $3\cdot 3^{n+1}-3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

So this is the expression I don't understand how to simplify $$3^{n+1}-3+2\cdot 3^{n+1}$$
Simplified, it should be
$$3\cdot 3^{n+1}-3$$

I have a problem in understanding where the other $ 3^{n+1}$ disappears and how we get $3 \cdot$

Could someone explain this to me with concrete examples?

Comment: The sum of the 1st and 3rd term is $3\cdot3^{n+1}$. And then you have the minus $3$ from the 2nd term.

Comment: How, I don't understand. Could you elaborate or show how it's done? @peter.petrov

Comment: I think you might be reading this as $3^{n+1} - (3+2)3^{n+1}$ when (by looking at the  answer) it is supposed to be $3^{n+1} - 3 + 2(3^{n+1})$

Comment: What is the 1st and 3rd term that are added? @layabout

Comment: 1st term is $3^{n+1}$ and 3rd is $2(3^{n+1})$.

Comment: @James replace $3^{n+1}$ with $x$. Then it's just $x-3+2x$. Can you solve that?

Comment: Now I understand, thank you for a good example! @CyclotomicField

Comment: I would say that $3^{n+2}-3$ is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. Let's take it step-by-step:
\begin{align}
\underbrace{3^{n+1}}-3 + 2 \cdot \underbrace{3^{n+1}}_{\text{}} &=\\
&= 3^{n+1} \cdot (1 + 2) - 3\\
&= 3 \cdot 3^{n+1} - 3\\
\end{align}
which by your claim ends your question. However, this can be simplified even further when you see that
\begin{align}
\underbrace{3} \cdot 3^{n+1} - \underbrace{3} = 3 \cdot (3^{n+1} - 1).
\end{align}